# Android - How to start a home replacement from scratch?

Tags: android, homescreen

I am looking to start a home replacement app, just to play around with the idea.

How can I make the app so it registers as a home replacement app, and just installs on the emulator, so when I click home, it asks if I want to use my app.

I searched pretty throughly on the Android SDK site, and couldn't find anything. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create an app that is designed to be run whenever the user presses the HOME key.

The important part is that you have an intent filter that catches the action `android.intent.action.MAIN` with categories `android.intent.category.HOME` and `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`.

For inspiration, look at the source code of Android's standard launcher [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git;a=tree).